# How to combine Multi Map entries based on common entry values

Tags: java, google-maps, hashmap

I have a Multimap structure, `Map<String, Set<String>>` as input. I want to group entries of this map if any two sets of entry values have a common element. Output should be of the format `Map<Set<String>, Set<String>>`  where each key will be a group of keys from the input map.

eg. given this input:

```
A -> [1,2]
B -> [3,4]
C -> [5,6]
D -> [1,5]
```

Output:

```
[A,C,D] -> [1,2,5,6]
[B] -> [3,4]
```

Here `A` & `D` have `1` as common element, `C` & `D` have `5` as common element. So `A`, `C`, `D` are merged into one key.

Comment: Do you have an algorithm in mind? I think the simple solution is to use loops that merge until nothing changes, starting with singleton sets derived directly from the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways you can solve this. One that I like (assuming you are using Java 8) is to implement this as a collector for a `Map.Entry` stream. Here's a possible implementation:

```
public class MapCollector {
    private final Map<Set<String>,Set<Integer>> result = new HashMap<>();

    public void accept(Map.Entry<String,Set<Integer>> entry) {
        Set<String> key = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(entry.getKey()));
        Set<Integer> value = new HashSet<>(entry.getValue());
        Set<Set<String>> overlapKeys = result.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(value::contains))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        overlapKeys.stream().forEach(key::addAll);
        overlapKeys.stream().map(result::get).forEach(value::addAll);
        result.keySet().removeAll(overlapKeys);
        result.put(key, value);
    }

    public MapCollector combine(MapCollector other) {
        other.result.forEach(this::accept);
        return this;
    }

    public static Collector<Map.Entry<String, Set<Integer>>, MapCollector, Map<Set<String>,Set<Integer>>> collector() {
        return Collector.of(MapCollector::new, MapCollector::accept, MapCollector::combine, c -> c.result);
    }
}
```

This can be used as follows:

```
Map<Set<String>,Set<Integer>> result = input.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(MapCollector.collector());
```

Most of the work is done in the `accept` method. It finds all overlapping sets and moves them to the new map entry. It supports parallel streams which could be useful if your map is massive.